# next.js cannot be started

Tags: reactjs, next.js

To set up the next.js environment, we ran the commands in the following order.
After running it, I ran yarn dev but got an error.

error

```
warning package.json: No license field
error Command "dev" not found.
```

Command executed

```
・yarn create next-app
・yarn add next react react-dom
・touch tsconfig.json
・yarn add --dev typescript @types/react @types/node
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "nextapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "10.0.4",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `"scripts"` modify the `"dev"` from `"dev": "next dev"` to `"dev": "next"`.

`"scripts"` should look like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  }
```